# Creating Jenkins Pipeline inside Job DSL script

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I can create pipelines by putting the following code into "Jenkinsfile" in my repository(called repo1) and creating a new item, through Jenkins GUI, to poll the repository.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine' 
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2' 
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package' 
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'target/*.jar', fingerprint: true
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo \'uploading artifacts to some repositories\''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I have a case where I am not allowed create new items through Jenkins GUI but have a pre-defined job which reads JobDSL files in a repository I provide. So, I need to create the same pipeline through JobDSL but I cannot find the corresponding syntax for all the things, for instance, I couldn't find 'agent' DSL command.

Here is a job DSL code I was trying to change.

```
pipelineJob('the-same-pipeline') {
  definition {
    cps {
      sandbox()
      script("""

        node {

          stage('prepare') {
              steps {
                  sh '''echo 'hello''''
              }
          }
        }
      """.stripIndent())      
    }
  }
}
```

For instance, I could not find 'agent' command. Is it really possible to have the exact pipeline by using job DSL?

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to create the pipeline item through jobDSL. So, the following jobDSL is creating another item which is just a pipeline.

```
pipelineJob('my-actual-pipeline') {
  definition {
    cpsScmFlowDefinition {
      scm {
        gitSCM {
          userRemoteConfigs {
            userRemoteConfig {
              credentialsId('')
              name('')
              refspec('')
              url('https://github.com/muatik/jenkins-as-code-example')
            }
          }
          branches {
            branchSpec {
              name('*/master')
            }
          }
          browser {
            gitWeb {
              repoUrl('')
            }
          }
          gitTool('')
          doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations(false)
        }
      }
      scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
      lightweight(true)
    }
  }
}
```

You can find the `Jenkinsfile` and my test repo here: https://github.com/muatik/jenkins-as-code-example